# Ссылки на методы android

Tags: android, rxjava

У меня есть метод который пишет изменения в лог:

```
 MoreReactiveList<Long> list = new MoreReactiveList<>();

    Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .take(10)
            .subscribe(list.adder());

    Observable.timer(4, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .take(10)
            .subscribe(list.remover());

    list.changes().subscribe(System.out::println);

    list.changes()
            .flatMap(e -> list.list().toList())
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Как сделать что бы вместо `System.out::println` я выводил результат в `TextView`?

Работал по єтому [примеру](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2015/06/subjects-part-1.html)

Comment: В чем вопрос? Напишите свой метод, который будет выводить результат в `TextView` и предайте его в `subscribe`.

Comment: Можете написать пример, пожалуйста .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private TextView mTextView; // Наш textView, куда выводить
```

---

```
list.changes()
            .flatMap(e -> list.list().toList())
            .subscribe(mTextView::setText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему с помощью лямбда-выражений:

```
 list.changes()
            .flatMap(e -> list.list().toList())
            .subscribe((text)-> {
                mLogcatTextView.setText((String)mLogcatTextView.getText()+text);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

С лямбдами так не заработает, функция должна выполнятся в @UIThreed. 
Сделайте отдельную функцию:

```
 @UiThread
public void setTextLog(String text) {
    mLogcatTextView.setText(mLogcatTextView.getText() + "\n" + text.toString());
}
```

Использую `AndroidAnnotation`